# Should the svd of a square matrix always compute a U and V which are inverses?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

I’m using a Scala library which (I believe) wraps a java library which does some linear algebra computations.
There is a function which is documented to return THE singular value decomposition.  First of all I was
under the impression that the SVD was not unique.  But ignoring that question for the moment.
The svd function in this library accepts a rectangular matrix, but I am always using a square matrix.
It returns (U,s,V) where U and V are nxn square matrices and s is a vector (1xn).
However, in some cases UV does not equal the identity.

Does this seem suspicious?

Sometimes the U and V given back are negative inverses of each other.
I.e., UV = -I.

Does that sound like a bug in the svd function?  Or does UV=I only if the matrix is positive definite?

For example, if I test it with a 1x1 matrix M=[-4.034101137641814], a number I obtained with a random number generator
then svd returns ([-1.0], [4.034101137641814],[1.0]) rather than  ([1.0], [-4.034101137641814],[1.0]) as I would expect.

Does it sound to you like a bug, or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Make a bunch of examples (or try to do it theoretically), and see if you can spot a connection between the determinant of the original matrix and the sign of $UV$.

Comment: I found a case where the determinant is 59.51636589963378, where uv is nowhere near the identity.